# Hide a export menu option item (not the entire export hamburger) item in view full screen mode high charts

Tags: angular, highcharts

The root cause of this request is exit from full screen mode in view full screen is  not appearing and instead of exit from full screen text still i am able to see view full screen button in full screen mode.

So the requirement is either i should be able to hide the view full screen button in full screen mode or exit from full screen needs to be displayed .

this is the piece of code i have added for exporting

```
 exporting: {
    csv: {
      columnHeaderFormatter: function(item, key) {
          if (!key) {
              return 'custom header'
          }
          return false
      }
  },
    enabled: true,
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
        menuItems: ["viewFullscreen","exitFullscreen", "printChart", "separator","downloadCSV","downloadXLS"]
    }
}},
```

Comment: The charts are dynamic which means based on api data length number of charts are being displayed. So expecting a solution which can be generic for all charts  thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what do you have in mind. Consider this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic when the chart is in the full-screen in the menu we can find 'Exit from the fullscreen mode". Is it wrong for you?